# Failed to execute action :action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main

Tags: ruby, logstash, elk

I have installed ELK stack version 7.0.0 on my CentOS7 VM and I faced with an issue during Logstash service start:

[ERROR] 2019-05-13 08:21:37.359 [Converge PipelineAction::Create] agent - Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"MultiJson::ParseError", :message=>"JrJackson::ParseError", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/multi_json-1.13.1/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:20:in `load'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/multi_json-1.13.1/lib/multi_json.rb:122:in`load'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.8.2/lib/avro/schema.rb:36:in `parse'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-codec-avro-3.2.3-java/lib/logstash/codecs/avro.rb:69:in`register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/base.rb:18:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:255:in`plugin'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:50:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:23:in`initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in`block in converge_state'"]}

Please help to figure out a way to resolve this issue. Similar installation on another Centos VM is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are cofiguration json format not parsing in logstash.yml file

put simple configuration like blow

```
input {     
  beats {
    port => 5044
 }
}
output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }  

 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["http://ip:9200"]
 }
}
```