# Logstash Error: agent - Failed to execute action

Tags: nginx, logging, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaFH2PcYI64) on how to use ELK stack for nginx logs.
I've created nginx.conf to configure how to get the logs but when i type: `bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/nginx.conf`

I get this error:

> [ERROR] 2020-11-13 14:59:15.254 [Converge
> PipelineAction::Create] agent - Failed to execute action
> {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
> :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of
> [A-Za-z0-9_-], [ \t\r\n], "#", "=>" at line 9, column 8 (byte
> 135) after input{\n\t\n   file{\n   path =>
> ["/var/log/nginx/access.log" , "/var/log/nginx/error.log"]\n
> type => "nginx"\n   }\n   filter{\n   \n   grok",
> :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in
> `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in` initialize'",
> "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in` initialize'",
> "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in
> `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:365:in` block
> in converge_state'"]}
> and here's my nginx.conf file:

```
input{
    
   file{
   path => ["/var/log/nginx/access.log" , "/var/log/nginx/error.log"]
   type => "nginx"
   }
   filter{
   
   grok{
    match => ["message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"]
    overwrite => ["message"]
   }
   mutate{
    convert => ["response","integer"]
    convert => ["bytes","integer"]
    convert => ["responsetime","float"]
   }
   geoip{
    source => "clientip"
    target => "geoip"
    add_tag => ["nginx-geoip"]
   }
   date {
    match ⁼> ["timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z"]
    remove_field => ["timestamp"]
   }
   useragent {
   source => "agent"
   } 
   }

output{
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "nginx-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  document_type => "nginx_logs"
 }
}

}
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108952/failed-to-execute-action-action-logstashpipelineactioncreate-pipeline-idm) but the answer didn't help.
Is there anyone familiar with logstash syntax and help figure out my error

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a } to close the input section. Insert it before the filter keyword.

Also, remove the last } in the file.

Comment: Thank you i thought that filter was inside input